Finding all the query_id that are trigerred by dashboard in Apache Superset
I have connected apache superset with trino and enabled metadata logging both in trino and superset, as result of which queries metadata like query_id, cpu_time , memory from trino and superset dashboard and their resp slices(charts) are being logged in db. Now i would like to make some dashboard level stats like dashboard overall memory and cpu usages in trino, for that i need to map all the queries that are trigerred while loading superset dashboard but i am not able to find this association od dashboard to its resp trigerred query_id in the metastore tables.
i tried to eanble metastore log both in superset so that dashboard and its chart info can be dumped and also enabled metatastore in trino so that query metadata can also be dumped.
